# Can Java ProccessBuilder use the same cmd window

Tags: java, cmd, processbuilder

A Java program runs from a cmd window. Program restarts itself and does the same thing. Works fine for the GUI yet there is no cmd window. Can ProcessBuilder use the same initial cmd window? I want to stream output back to the same cmd window.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by use same initial `cmd` window ? do you want to leverage variables set in that `cmd` session ? or you want to stream output back to same `cmd` ?

Comment: "program restarts itself", what do you mean by that? a java program that terminates/terminated can't restart itself.Since you are talking about a GUI, what cmd window are you talking about?

Comment: @Bree Welcome to SO. Please provide more details. Its always good to take some time and read the documentation about [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: A Java program runs from a cmd window. Program restarts itself and does the same thing. Works fine for the GUI yet there is no cmd window. Can ProcessBuilder use the same initial cmd window?

final ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
builder.command(command);
builder.start();
System.exit(0);

Works fine for GUI but no cmd line window to read what the program prints to cmd line

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `inheritIO`.

Just call

```
builder.inheritIO();
```

For further info take a look at the doc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO())